# Classifying PDF Text Documents based on the presence/absence of specific words in R

Tags: r, text-mining

I would like to be able to import PDF documents into R and classify them as either:

- Relevant (contains a specific string, for example, "tacos", **within the first 100 words**)
- Irrelevant (**DOES NOT** contain "tacos" within the first 100 words)

To be more specific, I would like to address the following questions:

1. Does a package(s) exist in R to perform this basic classification?
2. If so, is it possible to generate a dataset that would look something like this in R if I had 2 PDF documents with Paper1 containing at least one instance of the string, "tacos", in the first 100 words and Paper2 that DOES NOT contain at least one instance of the string, "tacos":

[image]

Any references to documentation/R packages/sample R code or mock examples related to this type of classification **using R** would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`pdftools`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pdftools/index.html) library and do something like this:

First, load the library and grab some pdf file names:

```
library(pdftools)
fns <- list.files("~/Documents", pattern = "\\.pdf$", full = TRUE)
fns <- sample(fns, 5) # sample of 5 pdf filenames...
```

Then define a function that reads a PDF file in as text and looks up the first `n` words. (It might be useful to check for errros, like *unknown password* or things like that - my ex. function returns `NA` for such cases.)

```
isRelevant <- function(fn, needle, n = 100L, ...) {
  res <- try({
    txt <- pdf_text(fn)
    txt <- scan(text = txt, what = "character", quote = "", quiet = TRUE) 
    any(grepl(needle, txt[1:n], ...))
  }, silent = TRUE)
  if (inherits(res, "try-error")) NA else res
}
res <- sapply(fns, isRelevant, needle = "mail", ignore.case=TRUE)
```

Finally, wrap it up and put it into a data frame:

```
data.frame(
  Document = basename(fns), 
  Classification = dplyr::if_else(res, "relevant", "not relevant", "unknown")
)
#   Document  Classification
# 1    a.pdf        relevant
# 2    b.pdf    not relevant
# 3    c.pdf        relevant
# 4    d.pdf    not relevant
# 5    e.pdf        relevant
```

Comment: Thanks @lukeA, I am still unsure of how to adapt this function to look for words, but this solution gets me pretty close! Would you be willing to update the function to look for n words instead of n characters?

Comment: @lukA, you are awesome! Thanks for your help!

Comment: one last question and I will leave you alone and give you the best answer award, what does the L at the end of 100L do? I can't seem to figure that out?

Comment: it's okay, if you don't see this, but thank you again for all of your help!

Comment: @MattReichenbach Your welcome. The L makes the 100 an integer value. Check out `class(100L)` versus `class(100)`. However, it's not important here for the function to work.

Comment: Okay great! Good to know! Still have much to learn, but this gives me a lot of ideas! Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

While @lukeA beat me to it, I wrote another small function that uses pdftools as well. The only real difference is that lukeA looks at the first `n`-characters, and my skript looks at the first `n` words.

This is how my approach looks

```
library(pdftools)
library(dplyr) # for data_frames and bind_rows

# to find the files better
setwd("~/Desktop/pdftask/")

# list all files in the folder "pdfs"
pdf_files <- list.files("pdfs/", full.names = T)


# write a small function that takes a vector of paths to pdf-files, a search term,
# and a number of words (i.e., look at the first 100 words)
search_pdf <- function(pdf_files, search_term, n_words = 100) {
  # loop over the files 
  res_list <- lapply(pdf_files, function(file) {
    # use the library pdftools::pdf_text to extract the text from the pdf
    content <- pdf_text(file)

    # do some cleanup, i.e., remove punctuation, new-lines and lower all letters
    content2 <- tolower(content)
    content2 <- gsub("\\n", "", content2)
    content2 <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", content2)

    # split up the text by spaces
    content_vec <- strsplit(content2, " ")[[1]]

    # look if the search term is within the first n_words words
    found <- search_term %in% content_vec[1:n_words]

    # create a data_frame that holds our data
    res <- data_frame(file = file, 
                      relevance = ifelse(found, 
                                         "Relevant",
                                         "Irrelevant"))
    return(res)
  }) 

  # bind the data to a "tidy" data_frame
  res_df <- bind_rows(res_list)
  return(res_df)
}

search_pdf(pdf_files, search_term = "taco", n_words = 100)

# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#                          file  relevance
#                         <chr>      <chr>
# 1         pdfs//pdf_empty.pdf Irrelevant
# 2         pdfs//pdf_taco1.pdf   Relevant
# 3 pdfs//pdf_taco_above100.pdf Irrelevant
```